# Can multiple subtypes be mapped to same javaclass?

Tags: java, json, jackson

The Json i try to map looks like this:

```
[{  
    "Id":"NumberType1",
    "Value":65
},
{  
    "Id":"Image",
    "Value":"picture.jpg"
},
{  
    "Id":"NumberType2",
    "Value":88
},
{  
    "Id":"NumberType3",
    "Value":22
}]
```

And I have configured the Subtype mapping like this in the super class `Detail`:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
        property = "Id", 
        defaultImpl=Detail.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(Image.class),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=NumberType.class, name="NumberType1"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=NumberType.class, name="NumberType2"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=NumberType.class, name="NumberType3")
})
public class Detail {
}
```

Unfortunately `NumberType2` and `NumberType3` is mapped towards the super class `Detail` rather than the NumberType class (As if annotation above was ignored)

[This](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html?showComment=1316718657074#c7698965513001100315) blog comment indicates this is maybe how it should be.. but any help is appriciated.

Can multiple subtypes be mapped to same java class (It works for the class set as `defaultImpl` in `@JsonTypeInfo`)?

(I can change the java-code, but not the json format)